# Invocable class does not appear in drop-down

Tags: invocable-method

I created a very simple class with an invocable method:

```
public class CKZUpdateAccountCreditLimit {

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void updateAccountCreditLimit(List<Id> invoiceIds) {
        // code would go here
    }

}
```

It does not appear in the drop-down of Apex Classes in Process Builder, however.  Is there something about this class that prevents it from being displayed in the drop-down options?  Or is there a user or profile setting I need to enable to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that the tests have run against this class in the target org. Go to the target org, `Setup | Develop | Apex Test Execution` choose the test for this invocable (if you haven't written one - then it needs to be written and deployed)

(same applies to Schedulable classes)

Comment: I'm using a Trialforce org.  I thought Apex test requirements didn't need to be met there.

Comment: @MichaelSobczak - I don't have experience w/ TrialForce but this behavior has certainly been observed in Enterprise orgs - give it a whirl and see if it clears up your issue